# how Indexing works in logical reads and what are the benefits

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2012, logical-reads

I want to reduce the logical reads to speed up the stored procedures execution time sql server, Later i come to know by using index i will find my solution.

I need to know how indexing works and its benefits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly. Without an index, SQL must begin with the first row and then read through the entire table to find the relevant rows. The larger the table, the more this costs. If the table has an index for the columns in question, SQL can quickly determine the position to seek to in the middle of the data file without having to look at all the data. This is much faster than reading every row sequentially.

BUT indexes slow down inserts and updates (which can become a really serious issue with locking) and cost disk space.

Read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175049.aspx) for the different indexes that exists in SQL server

Comment: thanks..but how the speed vary between clustered index and non-clustered.

Comment: It al comes down to fine-tuning your tables with the sql you are using. Check out the ececution plan to see inspect the reads